# How to make the blinking background in one color (notification)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a user receives a notification, I check it from the database and put the notification box in a blinking state. But I want to cancel the blinking when the user clicks to see the notification and make it one color. For example; when I click, the background will be red and doesn't change.

HTML:

```
<li id="notification-box" style="float:right; background-color:#4f5f6f;color: #1c87c9; ">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i></a> 
</li>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
        function change() {
          var doc = document.getElementById("notification-box");
          var color = ["#ff1818","#4f5f6f"];
          doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
          i = (i + 1) % color.length;
        }
        setInterval(change, 750);
</script>
```

I can do this with the following, but there is an icon(fa-bell-o) in the notification-box. When the user clicks on this icon, naturally it makes the background of the icon in one color, the notification-box continues to blink.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#notification-box').click(function(e){
        $(e.target).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    });
});
```

All suggestions are suitable for me; ajax, jquery, javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the blink feature using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) you need to first store its returned value in a variable like:

```
var timer = setInterval(change, 750);
```

and when you click on `$('#notification-box')` you just need to call [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) method to stop the timer , so that `change` function call also stops like:

```
$('#notification-box').click(function(e){
    $(e.target).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. clearinterval worked. To solve the problem for background color of the icon; I changed $ (e.target) to $ ('# notification-box').